# How to configure gmail integration to monitor only the inbox

Tags: 12.10, notification, gmail, notification-area

The new web application integration feature on 12.10 is able to link Gmail to the standard notification tray widget. It's a cool feature, but it's usefulness is diminished because it is activated ("turns blue") when there is any unread email in any label.

Is there a way to specify that I only want to be notified when there is unread email on **the inbox**?

Answer (score 0):

This level of customization isn't currently possible. There's a bug report about the problems that creates:

- [Messaging Menu is always in 'attention' state when there are archived, labeled, unread items](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1062914)